# Isomorphisms of $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism

I am to find the number of isomorphisms between $S_n \to S_n$. How do I proceed? One is the map which maps all the elements to itself.

So if $\varphi(ab)\to (cd)$ will be one case. Consider the case whe $n=20$. Now $\varphi(ab) \to (cd)(ef)$ because the number of order 2 cycles is $20_{C_{2}}$ and the number of 2 2-cycles is $(20_{C_{2}}×18_{C_{2}})/2$. Now if $\varphi$ is a isomorphism then $\varphi^{-1}$ is also an isomorphism so if $190$ elements are mapped to $270$ then $270$ should also be mapped to some $190$ elements.

Well I am really not able to conclude why this will not happen.

Comment: I'm confused--are you saying $n = 20$?  Where does the number 270 come from?

Comment: What do you know about the possible kernels of a group homomorphism?

Comment: Our professor discouraged us from using the kernel method and the first isomorphism theorem as it has yet not been taught in class.ofcourse I can back calculate so $A_n$,e and $S_n$ are the possible kernels and when $n=4$ it is the klein four group what next?

Comment: Do you know that $S_n$ is generated by $(12)$ and $(12\cdots n)$?

Comment: Do you know what the conjugacy classes of $S_n$ are? Do you know about inner automorphism? Do you know that an automorphism must send conjugacy classes to conjugacy classes?

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to spill the beans.

An isomorphism of a group with itself is called an automorphism.  The set of all such forms a group, denoted $\rm{Aut}(G)$, with function composition as the operation.

Interestingly enough, except for $S_2$ and $S_6$, we have $\rm{Aut}(S_n)\cong S_n$.

We know, for $n\gt2$, that $S_n$ is center less.  Thus it embeds as a subgroup of its automorphism group.

With a little work, one can show that all the automorphisms are inner ($n\ne6$).  This means $S_n$ is (in fact equal to) the automorphism group.

Inner automorphisms are the ones of the form $i_g(x)=gxg^{-1}\,,\forall x$.

That's all for now.

Comment: That's what I said.  Perhaps I should have reiterated.  @Aaron

Comment: Apologies, I don't know how I missed that.  Removing my comment.

Comment: No sweat @Aaron.